# Concatenation code that works similar to sumif

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a lookup conditional concatenation vba macro.

It should ideally lookup and concatenate texts in column B based on value in column A and output it as below if as i define the the lookup.

Example

Dataset:

```
A   B
Car Alex 
Car Kieth
Bus Jenny
Car Jessica
Taxi Dom
Taxi Sabrina
Car Dick
```

Lookup  Output

```
Car     Alex, Kieth, Jessica, Dick
```

I prefer a vba macro to a function as it ideally consumes less memory.

```
Sub positionbreach()

Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
Dim Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range

Set Search_in_col = Worksheets("CARS").Range("A2:A50")
Set Return_val_col = Worksheets("CARS").Range("B2:B50")

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For j = Last To 2 Step -1

    For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count

        If Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("CARS").Cells(j, 15) Then

        result = result & " " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value

        End If

    Next

Worksheets("CARS").Cells(j, 17) = Trim(result)

Results = ""

Next
End Sub
```

I am completely stuck just at the concatenation portion. Amended my code to where i am at

Grateful for any assistance.

My output is as follows

```
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Dom Sabrina Dom Sabrina Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Jenny Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Dom Sabrina Dom Sabrina Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Jenny Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Dom Sabrina Dom Sabrina Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Jenny
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Dom Sabrina Dom Sabrina Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Dom Sabrina Dom Sabrina
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick Dom Sabrina
Alex  Kieth Jessica Dick
```

Comment: That doesn't work?

Comment: Unofrtuantely it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Results = ""
```

is not the same as

```
result = ""
```

If you use Option Explicit you can avoid this type of error since it will warn you about undeclared variables.

Comment: Ah it was due to a typo, the concatenation works well now.